# Problems with dependencies adding new source files to lwip-tap

Tags: makefile, lwip

I am trying to add a new source file to lwip-tap (https://github.com/takayuki/lwip-tap) but I am encountering some problems when executing

```
$ make
```

I am following the way of implementation of other examples of the code. I am creating a "test.h" and a "test.c" with the same functioning as an udp example (changing the name of the functions to avoid conflicts).

Then I am adding dependencies in the makefile.in like I see the other dependencies are added:

First **-Ilwip-contrib/apps/test**

```
  srcdir = @srcdir@
  prefix = @prefix@
  exec_prefix = $(prefix)
  bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
  sbindir = $(exec_prefix)/sbin
  libexecdir = $(exec_prefix)/libexec
  datadir = $(prefix)/share

  IP_VERSION = 4
  CC = @CC@
  CPPFLAGS = @DEFS@ -I. -Ilwip-contrib/ports/unix/include \
    -Ilwip/src/include/ipv$(IP_VERSION) -Ilwip/src/include \
    -Ilwip-contrib/apps/chargen -Ilwip-contrib/apps/httpserver \
    -Ilwip-contrib/apps/tcpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/udpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/test @CPPFLAGS@
  CFLAGS = -pthread -Wall @CFLAGS@
  LDFLAGS = -pthread @LDFLAGS@
  LIBS = @LIBS@
  INSTALL = @INSTALL@
```

Second **lwip-contrib/apps/test/test.c**

```
SOURCES = \
  lwip/src/api/api_lib.c \
  lwip/src/api/api_msg.c \
  lwip/src/api/err.c \
  lwip/src/api/netbuf.c \
  lwip/src/api/netdb.c \
  lwip/src/api/netifapi.c \
  lwip/src/api/sockets.c \
  lwip/src/api/tcpip.c \
  lwip/src/core/def.c \
  lwip/src/core/dhcp.c \
  lwip/src/core/dns.c \
  lwip/src/core/init.c \
  lwip/src/core/mem.c \
  lwip/src/core/memp.c \
  lwip/src/core/netif.c \
  lwip/src/core/pbuf.c \
  lwip/src/core/raw.c \
  lwip/src/core/stats.c \
  lwip/src/core/sys.c \
  lwip/src/core/tcp.c \
  lwip/src/core/tcp_in.c \
  lwip/src/core/tcp_out.c \
  lwip/src/core/timers.c \
  lwip/src/core/udp.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/autoip.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/icmp.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/igmp.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/inet.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/inet_chksum.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip_addr.c \
  lwip/src/core/ipv4/ip_frag.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/asn1_dec.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/asn1_enc.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/mib2.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/mib_structs.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/msg_in.c \
  lwip/src/core/snmp/msg_out.c \
  lwip/src/netif/etharp.c \
  lwip-contrib/ports/unix/sys_arch.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/chargen/chargen.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/httpserver/httpserver-netconn.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/tcpecho/tcpecho.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/udpecho/udpecho.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/test/test.c \
  tapif.c \
  lwip-tap.c
```

I left untouched the final part of the makefile

```
OBJS := $(foreach f,$(SOURCES),$(notdir $(f:.c=.o)))
%.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
.PHONY: all check-syntax depend dep clean distclean
all: lwip-tap
lwip-tap: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o lwip-tap $(OBJS)
check-syntax:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -fsyntax-only $(CHK_SOURCES)
depend dep:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -MM $(SOURCES) >.depend
clean:
    rm -f config.cache config.log
    rm -f lwip-tap $(OBJS) *~
distclean: clean
    rm -f Makefile config.h config.status
    rm -rf autom4te.cache
ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
include .depend
endif
```

When I execute ./configure it works ok, but when I execute make, I get:

```
rr@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test/lwip-tap$ make
gcc -pthread -Wall -g -O2 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilwip-contrib/ports/unix/include -Ilwip/src/include/ipv4 -Ilwip/src/include -Ilwip-contrib/apps/chargen -Ilwip-contrib/apps/httpserver -Ilwip-contrib/apps/tcpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/udpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/test  -c 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

I  have realized that if I add the source to the SOURCES variable, it does not work like the other sources. For instance, If I add my source file here:

```
SOURCES = \
  lwip/src/api/api_lib.c \
  lwip-contrib/apps/test/test.c \
```

The output of make is:

```
gcc -pthread -Wall -g -O2 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilwip-contrib/ports/unix/include -Ilwip/src/include/ipv4 -Ilwip/src/include -Ilwip-contrib/apps/chargen -Ilwip-contrib/apps/httpserver -Ilwip-contrib/apps/tcpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/udpecho  -c lwip/src/api/api_lib.c
gcc -pthread -Wall -g -O2 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -Ilwip-contrib/ports/unix/include -Ilwip/src/include/ipv4 -Ilwip/src/include -Ilwip-contrib/apps/chargen -Ilwip-contrib/apps/httpserver -Ilwip-contrib/apps/tcpecho -Ilwip-contrib/apps/udpecho  -c 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'test.o' failed
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Why does it add "lwip/src/api/api_lib.c" at the end in the first case but it does not add "lwip-contrib/apps/test/test.c" in the second one?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared anywhere that the .o files depend on the .c files.

This pattern rule:

```
%.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
```

says you can build a .o file from nothing (no prerequisites) but then it uses the `$<` automatic variable which expands to the first prerequisite.  Somewhere the prerequisites must be explicitly defined, as:

```
sys_arch.o : lwip-contrib/ports/unix/sys_arch.c
```

but in your makefile you've not created those prerequisite statements, so the `$<` variable is empty (no prerequisites).

Comment: You are right, my .c compiles if I add that line. My question is, why do the rest of .c (the ones that I did not create, the ones that the lwip code has by default when downloading it) compile if it is not explicitly defined? might it be indicated somewhere?

Comment: Might be something defined in "configure" file?

Comment: I have edited my question for a better explanation.